# Outer corner round design balloon

Tags: html, css, chat

I'm trying to figure out how to make outer corner round design for chat bubble, to get desired result:

[image]

I've to use bubble as component over different background without same and solid color, but with some design element, so space around bubble must be transparent:

[image]

I've tried add element as separate part, but it seems like incorrect way to fix it in right position with change of screen size as separate part and hide lower end of form behind bubble square corner:

```css
.balloon {
  margin: 40px;
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  width: 200px;
  height: auto;
  background-color: rgb(114, 238, 110);
}

.txt {
  padding: 10px;
}

.right:after {
  content: " ";
  position: absolute;
  right: 0px;
  bottom: -20px;
  border: 12px solid;
  border-color: rgb(114, 238, 110) rgb(114, 238, 110) transparent transparent;
}

.left:after {
  content: " ";
  position: absolute;
  bottom: -20px;
  border: 22px solid;
  border-color: transparent transparent transparent rgb(114, 238, 110);
}

div.selectable div.active:after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  margin-right: -8px;
  width: 37px;
  height: 15px;
  border-right: 8px solid rgb(114, 238, 110);
  border-top: 8px solid rgb(114, 238, 110);
  border-top-right-radius: 39px;
}
```

```html
<div class="balloon right">
  <div class="txt">
    <p>Hello world right side</p>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="balloon left">
  <div class="txt">
    <p>Hello world left side</p>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="balloon right">
  <div class="txt">
    <p>Hello world</p>
  </div>
  <div class="selectable">
    <div class="active"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: How about an svg background? See [link]https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Tutorial/Paths#curve_commands for ideas.

Comment: @A Haworth Hello, I'm trying to figure out how to do it with css

Answer (score 4, accepted):

gradient background can do it:

```css
.box {
  width:200px;
  height:100px;
  display:inline-block;
  margin:10px;
  background:
    linear-gradient(green 0 0) top/100% calc(100% - 34px),
    radial-gradient(105% 100% at bottom left,transparent 97%,green) bottom right/40% 35px;
  background-repeat:no-repeat;
}
.left {
  background:
    linear-gradient(green 0 0) top/100% calc(100% - 34px),
    radial-gradient(105% 100% at bottom right,transparent 97%,green) bottom left/40% 35px;
  background-repeat:no-repeat;
}

body {
  background:linear-gradient(to right,lightblue,#f2f2f2);
}
```

```html
<div class="box">
</div>

<div class="box left">
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

**EDIT:**
You can use `:left` and `:right` with a **clip-path** and **polygon** shape to create the clip over the psuedo element.

```css
#chatbox {
  height: 600px;
  width: 600px;
  background: url('https://allhdwallpapers.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/05/circle-8.jpg') no-repeat;
}

.balloon {
  margin: 40px;
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  width: 200px;
  height: auto;
  background-color: rgb(114, 238, 110);
}

.txt {
  padding: 10px;
}

.right:before {
  content: ' ';
  position: absolute;
  right: 0px;
  bottom: -20px;
  height: 20px;
  width: 60px;
  background-color: rgb(114, 238, 110);
  clip-path: polygon(0 0, 100% 0, 100% 100%, 96% 80%, 91% 63%, 83% 45%, 72% 28%, 56% 15%, 39% 7%, 21% 3%);
  -webkit-clip-path: polygon(0 0, 100% 0, 100% 100%, 96% 80%, 91% 63%, 83% 45%, 72% 28%, 56% 15%, 39% 7%, 21% 3%);
}

.left:before {
  content: ' ';
  position: absolute;
  height: 20px;
  bottom: -20px;
  width: 60px;
  left: 0px;
  bottom: -20px;
  background-color: rgb(114, 238, 110);
  clip-path: polygon(0 0, 100% 0, 77% 2%, 59% 6%, 42% 13%, 26% 25%, 14% 41%, 8% 59%, 4% 78%, 0 100%);
  -webkit-clip-path: polygon(0 0, 100% 0, 77% 2%, 59% 6%, 42% 13%, 26% 25%, 14% 41%, 8% 59%, 4% 78%, 0 100%);
}

div.selectable div.active:after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  margin-right: -8px;
  width: 37px;
  height: 15px;
  border-right: 8px solid rgb(114, 238, 110);
  border-top: 8px solid rgb(114, 238, 110);
  border-top-right-radius: 39px;
}
```

```html
<div id="chatbox">
  <div class="balloon right">
    <div class="txt">
      <p>Hello world right side</p>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="balloon left">
    <div class="txt">
      <p>Hello world left side</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Hello, I've already tried this way, but space around the bubble must be transparent to use it on different background with design elements. Sorry, I've missed this note, please check my edit

Comment: @iose936 You can use javascript to get the color of your chat box bubbles parent element. Then set a variable in CSS using the root and change the root elements variable using javascript. See my updated answer...

Comment: @iose936 see my updated edit with clip-path on pseudo element.

Answer (score 0):

Hey I didn't use the `:after` implementation. Instead I used separate `div` elements and just giving them appropriate `height` and `right-top`/`left-top` `border-radius` like so :-

```css
.balloon {
      margin: 40px;
      display: inline-block;
      position: relative;
      width: 200px;
      height: auto;
      background-color: rgb(114, 238, 110) ;
    }
    
    .txt{
      padding: 10px;
    }
    
.bubble-right{
height:50px;
background:white;
border-top-right-radius:50%;
}

.bubble-left{
height:50px;
background:white;
border-top-left-radius:50%;
}
```

```html
<div class="balloon right">
      <div class="txt">
        <p>Hello world right side</p>
      </div>
      <div class='bubble-right'>
      </div>
    </div>
    
    <div class="balloon left">
      <div class="txt">
        <p>Hello world left side</p>
      </div>
      <div class='bubble-left'>
    </div>
```

Comment: Hello, your solution is good if you're using solid background color, but in my case, I've missed the note above, that I can't go this way, because I have to use it  on a different backgrounds and not just solid colors, but with some design element, the space around element  must be transparent/ I've edited my question with this note